# How to handle clicks on a view inside of a RecyclerView list item. Using data binding and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

All of the resources I've found are either in Java or only cover clicking the list item itself not a view inside of the list item.  I believe I am supposed to set this up inside the ViewHolder class but I am not sure how.  This is my ViewHolder class.

```
class ItemListAdapter(val clickListener : ItemListListener) : ListAdapter<Item , ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

class ItemViewHolder(private var binding : ItemListItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(item : Item, clickListener : ItemListListener) {

        binding.item = item
        binding.clickListener = clickListener
        
        // button that inside listItem that I want to respond to clicks
        // binding.addOneButton ???????
        

        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

And my listener

```
class ItemListListener(val clickListener : (singleItem : Item) -> Unit) {

fun onClick(item : Item){

    clickListener(item)


}
```

}

Other method calls in case they are relevant

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : ItemViewHolder , position : Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(item, clickListener)
}

companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem : Item , newItem : Item) : Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem : Item , newItem : Item) : Boolean {
        return oldItem.itemId == newItem.itemId
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent : ViewGroup ,
    viewType : Int
) : ItemViewHolder {
    return ItemViewHolder(ItemListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
}
```

Comment: What is `binding.clickListener`? Do you have something of this name in your XML?

Comment: It's my ItemListListener from second code group above.

Comment: I meant how are you using it in your XML? Have you set it as the `onClick` attribute of the xml button?

Comment: It is set as the `onClick` for the root view of the list item, a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Do you want two click listeners? One for root view and one for `addOneButton`?

Comment: Yes, if it's needed.  I want to have one thing happen if the root view is clicked and another if the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All,  Listener is supposed to be an Interface.

```
interface ItemListListener {
    fun onClick(item: Item,actionType:String) 
}
```

Then in Activity/Fragment class,implement this interface.
Initialize adapter.

```
recyclerView.adapter  = ItemListAdapter(this)
```

You can update your **ItemViewHolder** class with following code. Make it **inner** class, Then you'll not need to pass clickListener instance. And click listener should be registered in **init** method of View Holder class.

```
 inner class ItemViewHolder(private val binding : ItemListItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

              init {
                    binding.addOneButton.setOnClickListener {
                      clickListener.onClick(getItem(adapterPosition),"button")
                 }
                  binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                      clickListener.onClick(getItem(adapterPosition),"root")
                 }
             }
            fun bind(item : Item) {
                binding.item = item
                binding.executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
```

** *****Update***** **

After some research I got answer to your question.
Here's the solution.
Instead of an interface, You can pass Higher Order function to Adapter class.

```
class ItemListAdapter(val clickListener : (Item,String) -> Unit ):ListAdapter<Item , ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback)
```

In View Holder class

```
binding.addOneButton.setOnClickListener {
                      clickListener(getItem(adapterPosition),"button")
                 }
                  binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                      clickListener(getItem(adapterPosition),"root")
                 }
```

In Activity/Fragment

```
recyclerview.adapter = ItemListAdapter({item, action->
})
```

You can do it with Binding as well.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing an interface.  I heard that there is a different way it can be implemented in Kotlin.

Comment: @brandNoob Interface or Binding Listener inside XML are two ways to do it. I don't know the other way you are talking about.

Also if you want to handle root view click and addOneButton click separately. Then you can add one more parameter in onClick method of interface class.
I have updated the answer you can check.

Answer (score 0):

if its a click on the item you can set on the `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onClick(getItem(position)
}
```

If you need on a specific view inside your item you can set on the `bind` function

```
fun bind(item : Item, clickListener : ItemListListener) {
    binding.item = item
    binding.addOneButton.setOnClickListener {
         clickListener.onClick(item)
    }
    
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this already, but strangely the click only ended up registering on the first list item of the recycler view.